# Prove that $\int_E f \, du = \lim \int_E f_n \, du$ and counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

1.

If $(f_n)\in M^+(X,\textbf{X})$ and $f_n$ converges to $f$, and $$\displaystyle\int f\,\text{d}\mu = \lim_n \int f_n\,\text{d}\mu < \infty,$$ prove that $$\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu = \lim_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu$$
for each $E\in \textbf{X}$

Can someone prove step-by-step on this? Now, I am rather stuck!

2.

Why is the condition that $\displaystyle \lim_n \int f_n \, du < +\infty$ important?

if the condition $\displaystyle \lim_n \int f_n\, d\mu < +\infty$ is dropped, can you give a counterexample that the conclusion may fail?

Comment: Have you seen the Dominated Convergence Theorem yet? If so, then the first question seems to be perfectly suited to this theorem.

Comment: Yes. But still I have no idea how to apply the theorem to this problem. Could you please prove it step-by-step?

Comment: Also, so I'm clear on notation, $M_+(X,\textbf{X})$ is the set of non-negative measurable functions on the set $X$, and $E$ is measurable (being in the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable subsets of $X$)?

Comment: And finally, is this HW? If so, I'm not going to provide a step-by-step proof, but I am willing to provide some leading hints.

Comment: Notations are clear. + should be on the upper right corner and E should be on the lower corner. Not HW. I am reading Bartle's book but I found it hard to follow sometimes...

Comment: Are these functions $f_n$ such that $f_{n}\le f_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: I was trying to construct a dominating function, and that doesn't seem obvious at all, since $\sup_n f_n$ need not be integrable, even if $f_n$ is. It's not obvious how you would apply monotone convergence.

Comment: @daniels_pa not necessarily

Comment: Could you please improve your notation. Put E where it should be and + where it should be also $M_+(X,\textbf{X})$ makes little sence i think you meant $(X,\Sigma)$ ?

Comment: Just to clarify instead of $\int E f\space du$ it should be $\int_E f du$ and same on the limit integral ?

Comment: @daniels_pa Yes. Thanks for that. I am learning how to improve the notations

Comment: I have a counterexample to #2 in mind. I reformatted the question in LaTeX (let me know if it is correct as written)

Comment: Did you learn [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)  ?

Comment: That was the next thought I was working on. Haven't gotten the full argument written up yet though.

Comment: @Nicholas Stull Thanks! It is correct now.

Comment: @daniels_pa Yes. It is in Bartle's Chapter 4

Answer (score 1):

Just apply [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)

$$
\int_E\varliminf_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_n d\mu
 =\int_E f d\mu\le \varliminf_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_E f_n d\mu \le \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_E f_n d\mu \le \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_E f_n d\mu \le \int_E f d\mu = \int_E \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_n d\mu
$$

From this its obvious that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_E f_n d\mu =\int_E f d\mu
$$
This applies to all positive measurable functions $f$.
The standard Fatous statement applies even for the case when the functions are infinite. But the reverese fatous statements requires the $\int_E f d\mu < \infty$
Since in your  case $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_n = f$  and exists

Comment: I was typing my answer as you posted yours. Nice catch suggesting Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: When we aim at simplicity we usually get the same results :)

Comment: I think there might be a way to do this using one of the convergence theorems, but I doubt it's any more concise. +1 of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple example for #2:

Let $X=\mathbb{R}_{>0}=(0,\infty)$, with $\textbf{X}$  the usual $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-measurable sets, with $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $X$. Define 
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & x \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
0 & x>\frac{1}{n}\end{cases}$$

First, we notice that, with $E = X$, $$\int_E f_n(x)\,\text{d}\mu(x)=\infty$$
for every $n$, so the limit is certainly nonzero. On the other hand, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ is zero almost everywhere, hence $\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu = 0$.

For #1, this seems to be one approach:

By Fatou's Lemma, $$\int_E \liminf_n f_n\,\text{d}\mu \leq \liminf_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu$$
Likewise, by the Reverse Fatou's Lemma,
$$\limsup_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu \leq \int_E \limsup_n f_n\,\text{d}\mu$$

Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$, then $f_n\to f$ pointwise $\mu$-almost everywhere on $E$, for every $E\in\textbf{X}$.

Hence $\limsup_n f_n = \liminf_n f_n = f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $E$, and we're done, because we then have:

$$\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu = \int_E \liminf_n f_n\,\text{d}\mu \leq \liminf_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu \leq \limsup_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu \leq \int_E \limsup_n f_n\,\text{d}\mu=\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu$$

In particular, this shows that $\displaystyle\lim_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu$ exists, and as a direct consequence, shows
$$\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu = \lim_n \int_E f_n\,\text{d}\mu$$